# Multi-file script execution from command line

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I have multiple .sql script files and want to execute them one by one in batch file with proper logging mechanism.

I wrote below batch command to solve the problem

```
@ECHO OFF

SET SQLCMD="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE"
SET PATH="C:\Users\sql_scripts\"
SET SERVER="server_name"
SET DB="database"
SET LOGIN="user_name"
SET PASSWORD="password"
SET OUTPUT="C:\Users\sql_scripts\output\OutputLog.txt"

CD %PATH%

ECHO %date% %time% > %OUTPUT%
for %%f in (*.sql) do (
    %SQLCMD% -S %SERVER% -d %DB% -U %LOGIN% -P %PASSWORD% -i %%~f -b >> %OUTPUT%
)
```

But it has few problems that I want to solve as listed below :

1. I want to create dynamic out put file names based on input file name.  Example if input sql file
   name is "test.sql" then I want to create output file in "output" folder with name "test.sql".
   Currently It writes all the log to one file i.e. OutputLog.txt
2. I want to show output log with script of execution to identify which script produced what
   output. Let's say in one script file 5 scripts present then in output file I want to show the
   script and its output log.

Comment: 1. You have to use `OUTPUT`-variable as part of file names: `SET "OUTPUT=C:\\Users\sql_scripts\output\OutputLog-"`.  Then add SQL-file name to output file (in your FOR-cycle) `>> %OUTPUT%%%~nf.txt`. Your output log file name shall be like: `OutputLog-test.txt`

Comment: To change the `OutputLog.txt` name by each one of the input file names just change `SET OUTPUT="C:\Users\sql_scripts\output\OutputLog.txt"` by `SET OUTPUT="C:\Users\sql_scripts\output\%%~Nf.txt"`  If you want that each *.txt output file include its creation date and time, you have to move the corresponding `ECHO` command _inside_ the `for` loop _and_ change the variables expansion by a Delayed Expansion ones: `ECHO !date! !time! > %OUTPUT%` (and EnableDelayedExpansion in a `setlocal` command at beginning)